# When to use Haskell monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm implementing a combinatorial optimization algorithm in Haskell:

```
Given an initial candidate solution, repeat until stopping criteria are met:

  1. Determine possible moves
  2. Evaluate possible moves
  3. Choose a move
  4. Make move, record new candidate solution, update search state
```

I could write functions for steps 1-4 and chain them together inside a recursive function to handle looping and passing state from one iteration to the next, but I have a vague idea that monads apply.

What's the best way to express this kind of procedure in Haskell?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The best way to express this sort of iterative procedure in Haskell is as an *infinite list* of each successive result.  Piecing together your four steps yields a notion of a function from a solution to a different (better) solution; all you need to do is apply this infinitely many times.  The user of your function can then use any list function to get the answer: `solve s0 !! numIterations`, or `find stoppingCondition $ solve s0`, or whatever you want.

In order to get here, let's write out the types for each of these functions.

1. `moves  :: Solution -> [Move]`
   Given a possible solution, figure out the possible changes you can make.
2. `value  :: Solution -> Move -> Double`
   Given a solution and a move, evaluate it and record that value as some real number.
3. `choose :: Solution -> [Move] -> Move`
   Given a solution and a list of moves, pick the best one.
4. `apply  :: Solution -> Move -> Solution`
   Given a move, apply it to an existing solution to get a new one.

You want to write a function with a type something like `solve :: Solution -> (Solution -> Bool) -> Solution` which takes an initial solution and a stopping condition to execute your algorithm.

Instead, let's make this an infinite list; this means that you'll just remove the predicate and have `Solution -> [Solution]`.

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

-- moves, value, and apply are domain-specific
choose :: Solution -> [Move] -> Move
choose s ms = maximumBy (comparing $ value s) ms

solve :: Solution -> [Solution]
solve = iterate $ \s -> apply s . choose s $ moves s
```

Here, the key is `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`, which repeatedly applies a function to a value and gives you the results—exactly the description of your algorithm.

However, the way I'd really write this would be the following:

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

solve :: Ord o => (s -> [m]) -> (s -> m -> o) -> (s -> m -> s) -> s -> [s]
solve moves value apply = iterate step
  where step   s = apply s . choose s $ moves s
        choose s = maximumBy (comparing $ value s)
```

The advantage of this is that you can reuse this same generic structure for *any* problem domain.  All you need to do is to provide the `moves`, `value`, and `apply` functions!  And depending on my mood, I might rewrite that as this:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

solve :: Ord o => (s -> [m]) -> (s -> m -> o) -> (s -> m -> s) -> s -> [s]
solve moves value apply = iterate step
  where step   = (.) <$> apply <*> choose <*> moves
        choose = maximumBy . comparing . value
```

Here, we use applicative notation to say that we're effectively just doing `(.) apply choose moves` (which is just `apply . choose $ moves`) in a context where each of those functions is implicitly passed a parameter `s` (the reader applicative).  If we really wanted to tersify things, we could write

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

solve :: Ord o => (s -> [m]) -> (s -> m -> o) -> (s -> m -> s) -> s -> [s]
solve moves value apply =
  iterate $ (.) <$> apply <*> maximumBy . comparing . value <*> moves
```

Any of these snippets will do exactly what you need.  (Proviso: there are no effects/monads in any of your functions, so randomness is out.  You make this monadic easily, though.)

---

Just for kicks, though, let's think about the `State` monad.  This represents a computation with some sort of environment, so that `State s a` is isomorphic to `s -> (a,s)`—something which can see the state and potentially update it.  Here, all the `Solution ->`s on the left of your function signatures would disappear, as would the `-> Solution`s on the right.  That would leave you with

1. `moves  :: State Solution [Move]`
2. `value  :: Move -> State Solution Double`
3. `choose :: [Move] -> State Solution Move`
4. `apply  :: Move -> State Solution ()`

This means that you would have some monadic action `step`:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

choose :: [Move] -> State Solution Move
choose = let val m = do v <- value m
                        return (m,v)
         in fst . maximumBy (comparing snd) <$> mapM val ms

step :: State Solution ()
step = apply =<< choose =<< moves
```

You could make this more point-free, or make it polymorphic just as above, but I won't do that here.  The point is that once you have `step`, you can generate answers with `runState . last $ replicateM_ numIterations step`, or given a `whileM` function, `runState $ whileM (stoppingCondition :: State Solution Bool) step`.  Again, the user can decide how to stop it.  Your `moves` and `value` functions would probably query the state with `get :: State s s`; `apply` would probably use `modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()` to tweak the state without needing to pull it back out.  You can see the similarity with the structure from above in these types; and in fact, you can see that structure in the definition of `step`, as well.  Each one says "string together `apply`, `choose`/`value`, and `moves`", which is the definition of your algorithm.

---

The take-home message from both of these is that you want to avoid explicit loops/recursion, as you so rightly realized.  If you think about this algorithm imperatively, then the `State` monad seems like a natural structure, as it hides exactly those imperative features you were thinking of.  However, it has downsides: for instance, everything has become monadic, and—worst of all—functions other than `apply` are able to change the saved solution.  If you instead imagine this algorithm as producing a *new* result each time, you get the notion of `step :: Solution -> Solution`, and from there you can use `iterate` to get a well-behaved infinite list.

Comment: I like this `solve` abstraction better than my straight translation into imperative `State` monad code. +1

Comment: +1 Wow! What a versatile answer for such a rather vague question! Comprehensive and canny!

Comment: You can change `[a]` to `Monad m => m a` for good measure. Now solve is even more generic.

Comment: @trinithis: Which list are you referring to?  I don't think there's a good way to do that for the output of `iterate`, but there are multiple lists in the algorithm.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was getting ahead of myself. I was referring to `solve :: Ord o => (s -> [m]) -> (s -> m -> o) -> (s -> m -> s) -> s -> [s]`. I wonder how useful a function like `iterate' f x = mplus (return x) $ iterate' f (f x)` would be outside of a list context. Perhaps with a list monad transformer...

Comment: @trinithis: Funnily enough, I was just looking at [monadic lists](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/List), which are list monad transformers, and the package provides [`iterateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/List/0.4.2/doc/html/Data-List-Class.html#v:iterateM) with a type signature roughly equivalent to the (more restrictive) [`Monad m => (a -> m a) -> m a -> ListT m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/List/0.4.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-List-Funcs.html#v:iterateM).

Comment: Which is the advantage of your solution with `Control.Applicative` with respect to the previous with simple function application and comopsition, please? I really don't get it, the only difference I see is that I'm not able to even read the types of the applicative one :)

Comment: @Riccardo: There are five code blocks in my answer.  Code block five is the state monad one, which is of course very different; code blocks two through four are all different ways of writing the same thing.  So this means that the two solutions with `Control.Applicative` are the same as solution number two, and they even have the same type signature.  Are you asking about the advantage of two though four, which just have the top-level `solve` function, versus number one, with the top-level `choose` and `solve`?

Comment: @AntalS-Z: I mean, is there a difference (efficiency, mantainability or whatever) between the 2nd and 3rd solutions?

Comment: @Riccardo: No difference except for what you've noticed—one uses applicatives. (There could conceivably be a tiny difference in that you're using more higher-order combinators, but you'd need to profile to check that.) To understand what's going on, check out the reader monad/applicative functor; the idea is that `(.) <$> apply <*> choose <*> moves` is the same as `(.) apply choose moves` (or `apply . choose $ moves`), *except* for the extra structure.  In this case, the structure is reading from an environment; *i.e.*, being passed an implicit parameter (the `s` from the 2nd version).

Comment: @AntalS-Z: Thank you. I had some problems in reading `(.) <$> apply`, but now I see that it's needed to write the whole expression without parentheses. `apply <*> (choose <*> moves)` would be the same, right?

Comment: @Riccardo: …Why yes!  I didn't notice that, so it wasn't some principled parenthesis-avoidance thing.  I'm having some trouble grasping the intuition behind it, though, although I see perfectly clearly why it works.  Gotta love Haskell, right?  :-)

Comment: @AntalS-Z: Oh yes, I really love Haskell even if I'm still grasping the basics.
About my intuition: `f <*> g` for functions has the effect to fix `g x` as the second parameter of `f`, i.e. `f x (g x)`. I think about the expression from the first function you want to apply, so `choose <*> moves` is a function that takes a strategy and returns the best move: that's exactly the function you want to apply to the first parameter of `apply` to obtain its second: `apply x ((choose <*> moves) x)`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a pseudocodey sketch of how you might use the [`State`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) monad to thread the search state through the computation:

```
import Control.Monad.State

type SearchState = ...
type Move = ...
type Fitness = ...

determineMoves :: State SearchState [Move]
determineMoves = do
  -- since determineMoves is in the State monad, we can grab the state here
  st <- get
  ...

evaluateMoves :: [Move] -> [(Move, Fitness)]
evaluateMoves = ...

chooseMove :: [(Move, Fitness)] -> Move
chooseMove = ...

-- makeMove is not itself monadic, but operates on the SearchState
-- type we're threading through with the State monad
makeMove :: Move -> SearchState -> SearchState
makeMove m st = ...

loop :: State SearchState ()
loop = do
  moves <- determineMoves
  let candidates = evaluateMoves moves
      move = chooseMove candidates
  -- we pass a function (SearchState -> SearchState) to modify in 
  -- order to update the threaded SearchState
  modify (makeMove move)
  loop
```

Notice that even though your main computation is in the state monad, not every component has to be in the monad. Here, `evaluateMoves` and `chooseMove` are non-monadic, and I've used `let` to show you how to explicitly integrate them into a `do` block. Once you get comfortable with this style, though, you'll probably want to get comfortable using `<$>` (aka `fmap`) and function composition to get more succinct:

```
loop :: State SearchState ()
loop = do
  move <- (chooseMove . evaluateMoves) <$> determineMoves
  modify (makeMove move)
  loop
```