# Program design in Haskell: how to do simulation without mutability

Tags: haskell, simulation

I have a question about the best way to design a program I'm working on in Haskell. I'm writing a physics simulator, which is something I've done a bunch in standard imperative languages, and usually the main method looks something like:

```
while True:
  simulationState = stepForward(simulationState)
  render(simulationState)
```

And I'm wondering how to do something similar in Haskell. I have a function `step :: SimState -> SimState` and a function `display :: SimState -> IO ()` that uses HOpenGL to draw a simulation state, but I'm at a loss as to how to do this in a "loop" of sorts, as all of the solutions I can come up with involve some sort of mutability. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Haskell, so it's entirely possible that I'm missing a very obvious design decision. Also, if there's a better way to architect my program as a whole, I'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my opinion, the right way to think about this problem is not as a loop, but as a list or other such infinite streaming structure.  I gave [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7112113/237428) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7111522/237428); the basic idea is, as [C. A. McCann wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9548998/237428), to use `iterate stepForward initialState`, where [`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:iterate) “returns an infinite list of repeated applications of [`stepForward`] to [`initialState`]”.

The problem with this approach is that you have trouble dealing with a *monadic* step, and in particular a monadic rendering function.  One approach would just be to take the desired chunk of the list in advance (possibly with a function like `takeWhile`, possibly with manual recursion) and then `mapM_ render` on that.  A better approach would be to use a different, intrinsically monadic, streaming structure.  The four that I can think of are:

- [The iteratee package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iteratee), which was originally designed for streaming IO.  I think here, your steps would be a source (`enumerator`) and your rendering would be a sink (`iteratee`); you could then use a pipe (an `enumeratee`) to apply functions and/or do filtering in the middle.
- [The enumerator package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enumerator), based on the same ideas; one might be cleaner than the other.
- [The newer pipes package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), which bills itself as “iteratees done right”—it's newer, but the semantics are, at least to me, significantly clearer, as are the names (`Producer`, `Consumer`, and `Pipe`).
- [The List package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/List-0.4.2), in particular its `ListT` monad transformer.  This monad transformer is designed to allow you to create lists of monadic values with more useful structure than `[m a]`; for instance, working with infinite monadic lists becomes more manageable.  The package also generalizes many functions on lists into [a new type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/List/0.4.2/doc/html/Data-List-Class.html).  It provides an `iterateM` function twice; the [first time](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/List/0.4.2/doc/html/Data-List-Class.html#v:iterateM) in incredible generality, and the [second time](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/List/0.4.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-List-Funcs.html#v:iterateM) specialized to `ListT`.  You can then use functions such as [`takeWhileM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/List/0.4.2/doc/html/Data-List-Class.html#v:takeWhileM) to do your filtering.

The big advantage to reifying your program’s iteration in some data structure, rather than simply using recursion, is that your program can then do useful things with control flow.  Nothing too grandiose, of course, but for instance, it separates the “how to terminate” decision from the “how to generate” process.  Now, the user (even if it's just you) can separately decide when to stop: after *n* steps?  After the state satisfies a certain predicate?  There's no reason to bog down your generating code with these decisions, as it's logically a separate concern.

Comment: Your list seems to be missing [the `monad-loops` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops), which I think is actually the clearest demonstration of the approach.

Comment: Fantastic -- I've been looking for a reason to learn iteratees. I'll take a look at the pipes package. Thanks so much!

Comment: it is overkill for the original question, but for sake of those who might come after I think we ought to mention [Functional Reactive Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154701/help-understanding-arrows-in-haskell) in particular [Yampa/Animas](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yampa).

Comment: @C.A.McCann: That package seems to take a slightly different approach (combinator-based as opposed to data-structure–based), which I think your answer covers better anyway.  (The package is also lacking any `iterate`-type combinators that I could find.)

Comment: @AntalS-Z: True, but I think it's really the same underlying approach--reifying the recursion from those combinators relates to `ListT` in roughly the same way that the recursion combinators in `Data.List` relate to plain lists; likewise, they emphasize the recursion and the final result, while stream-processing emphasizes aspects of the intermediate steps. Understanding each gives better insight into what's going on, I think.

Answer (score 22):

Well, if drawing successive states is *all* you want to do, that's pretty simple. First, take your `step` function and the initial state and use [the `iterate` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aiterate). `iterate step initialState` is then an (infinite) list of each simulation state. You can then map `display` over that to get IO actions to draw each state, so together you'd have something like this:

```
allStates :: [SimState]
allStates = iterate step initialState

displayedStates :: [IO ()]
displayedStates = fmap display allStates
```

The simplest way to run it would be to then use [the `intersperse` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aintersperse) to put a "delay" action between each display action, then use [the `sequence_` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3asequence_) to run the whole thing:

```
main :: IO ()
main = sequence_ $ intersperse (delay 20) displayedStates
```

Of course that means you have to forcibly terminate the application and precludes any sort of interactivity, so it's not really a good way to do it in general.

A more sensible approach would be to interleave things like "seeing if the application should exit" at each step. You can do that with explicit recursion:

```
runLoop :: SimState -> IO ()
runLoop st = do display st
                isDone <- checkInput
                if isDone then return () 
                          else delay 20 >> runLoop (step st)
```

My preferred approach is to write non-recursive steps instead and then use a more abstract loop combinator. Unfortunately there's not really good support for doing it that way in the standard libraries, but it would look something like this:

```
runStep :: SimState -> IO SimState
runStep st = do display st
                delay 20
                return (step st)

runLoop :: SimState -> IO ()
runLoop initialState = iterUntilM_ checkInput runStep initialState
```

Implementing the `iterUntilM_` function is left as an exercise for the reader, heh.

Comment: The iterate/fmap solution is awesome, but I'm going to go with the recusion method. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 13):

Your approach is ok, you just need to remember that loops are expressed as recursion in Haskell:

```
simulation state = do
    let newState = stepForward state
    render newState
    simulation newState
```

(But you definietly need a criterion how to end the loop.)

Comment: Just to confirm, this won't stack overflow because it's tail-recursion?

Comment: It is neither tail recursive nor should it stack overflow :) Give it a try, or try one of the other solutions that sequence a list of rendered states.

Comment: @haldean It won't overflow the stack, though for different reasons. Tail recursion is not as useful or important in Haskell as in other languages, due to laziness.